# Hibernate join issue

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, hql

I'm trying to execute a simple join query, but it does't work. here is an example :
I have two tables **dept** and **empl**
[image]

what I'm trying to do is accessing **RESP.MAT** and **DEPT.NAME**, so that **ALL** RESP.MAT appear.
for that reason I use this query :

```
select d.name, r.mat from resp p left join dept d on d.respId=r.id where d.type='Atype' and r.info='INF'
```

which works fine (it shows all RESP.MAT and it correspondant DEPT.NAME if exist if not null), but when I tried to run it using **HQL**it only shows **RESP.MAT** which have a **DEPT.NAME** (so there is no null values ) here is the query :

```
select d.name, r.mat from dept d right join d.resp r where d.type='Atype' and r.info='INF'
```

Comment: so... 

1-typo in the first query should be "resp r" i believe

2-why have you changed the query?

Comment: the first query returns ,**all**  r.mat and the correspondent d.name if exist if not null. however, the second request returns **only** the r.mat that have f.name